# Browser affecting CSS Grid?

Tags: css, frontend, css-grid, web-frontend

I am learning CSS Grids from an online course, but basic 12 column layout grid is behaving very weird in my browser. I did ask the instructor but he was clueless too. Hence, I am unable to move forward in getting it right. So basically, the Grids are always either **having leftover space **or **overflowing with a scrollbar**, even when I do the exact code as the instructor. I thought maybe my pc's display is the problem but whatever scale I use, the problem persists. I am using chrome, but even firefox gives issues.
The grid structure is

```
#content{
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12,1fr);
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px,auto);
    position: relative;
}
```

These are my display settings with different scaling options:
Scale 100% Resolution 1920 x 1080
[System Display Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCtfm.png)

This is how a grid looks with scale 100% in 12-column layout.
[Scale 100%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hOEV.png)

This is how a grid looks with scale 125% in 12-column layout.
[Scale 125%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R49WC.png)

This is how a grid looks with scale 150% in 12-column layout.
[Scale 150%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93afv.png)

Comment: it's most likely `width: 100vw` that's causing an issue regarding the scrollbar, not your `grid` layout. what browser is your instructor using?

Comment: No its not. That tried without that too. I might as well edit the post for clarity. Thanks for bringing it up.

Comment: my instructor was using firefox. I had used it too but the grid was still off. But does chrome have an issue with Grids in general?

Comment: Could you give enough code to demonstrate the problem. I don't at the moment understand why you expect not to get a gap given the use of minmax, but of course I don't know enough about the overall context. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: yes this is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mpp00/cje6btnx/
in display scale of 150% it gives a very slight scroll
in display scale of 1000% and 125% it gives a visible gap below